# System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'SelectedObjectCollection' to type ,System.Collections.Generic.lEnumerable'1[System.String]

Tags: vb.net, parallel-processing, runtime-error

System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'SelectedObjectCollection' to type ,System.Collections.Generic.lEnumerable'1[System.String]

I need help understanding this runtime error.  I am fairly sure that the below is the problem, but have not been able to find a solution that works.

**Parallel.ForEach(Of String)(Me.clb1.SelectedItems,
Sub(clb1)**

**Parallel.ForEach(of String)(Me.CheckedListBox1.SelectedItems,
Sub(xxx)  <-Not sure what goes here.**

The error message highlights the entire Sub but the rest was cut and pasted from working code.

Comment: `ListBox.SelectedItems` is a specialized collection, `SelectedObjectCollection`, derived from IList. Each element is an Object, not a String. That method requires an `IEnumerable<T>` or a partitioner -- Don't pass something named `clb1` to the Lambda -- What if you change it in `clb1.SelectedItems.OfType(Of Object)` (removing `(Of String)`)? What Type each Item in the collection actually contains? Do you have `Option Strict` set to `On`

Comment: OfType would work but the point of that method is to filter items by type. In this case, the OP wants all items. What's needed is to turn an IEnumerable into an IEnumerable(Of T), which is what the Cast(Of T) method exists for.

Comment: I replaced the clb1 with what it was short for.   I seem to be brain dead right now and getting my head around what is being said.  Could someone give me an example or point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I read the instructions of Lambda and found a simpler example.  The is dawned on me what I needed to do.

```
    For cnt = 0 To ListBox1.Items.Count - 1
        MyFiles.Add(ListBox1.Items(cnt))
    Next

    Parallel.ForEach(MyFiles, Sub(F)
```

Now I need to fix the code to handle the multi-threading code, but that is another question that I am not ready to ask yet.  Thanks.